# Checking where Differentiable and Analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

Describe the set of the points in the complex plane where the following functions of complex variable $z$ are differentiable and the sets of points where the functions are analytic.

a) $f(z) = \frac{1}{e^z + 1}$

Solution: So $f'(z) = -\frac{e^z}{(1+e^z)^2}$. So is it differentiable everywhere? Also for checking if it is analytic I should check whether $u_x = v_y, \: u_y = -v_x$? How can I write this in terms of $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$?

b) $f(z) = (z-1)|z-1|^2$

Solution: So $f'(z) = 3(z-1)^2$? So is it differentiable everywhere? Also for checking if it is analytic I should check whether $u_x = v_y, \: u_y = -v_x$? How can I write this in terms of $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$?

Comment: For (a), the function isn't differentiable (or even continuous) at infinitely many points in the plane, corresponding to $e^z = -1$.

Comment: Ahhh right ok. That makes sense.